# bootstrap & jquery in webpack encore symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I want to include bootstrap and jquery to a symfony 4 project using webpackEncore, but i don't want to use a cdn script, i do want to use a downloaded files... so, after installing encore to the project, i put bootstrap and jquery files in assets folder like shown at the image below:
[image]

then, in webpack.config.js, these are the codes :

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    
    // JS
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('bootstrap_js', './assets/js/bootstrap.js')
    .addEntry('fontawesome_js', './assets/js/fontawesome/fontawesome.js')
    .addEntry('jquery', './assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.js')

    // CSS
    .addStyleEntry('bootstrap_css', './assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css')
    .addStyleEntry('fontawesome_css', './assets/css/fontawesome/fontawesome.css')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

and there is my template:
[image]

but when i run encore, it fails, it says that there are a missing required dependencies for bootstrap:
[image]

What should i fix the problem
NB: I don't want to use cdn for bootstrap and jquery...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have downloaded source file from Bootstrap and FontAwesome. You must download a compiled, minified version so all the dependencies of these libraries are already included.

You should download https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js and use `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.css`

If you have problems with FontAwesome too, the process should be relatively the same (take the compiled minified versions)

> NB : you should really refrain from downloading the files directly, but rather use a package manager like `npm` or `yarn` to include your dependencies, and then import them in your own CSS / JS files

Comment: yes there is the minified file for both bootstsrap css and js, you can noticed the arrow before files in the picture :)

Comment: I don't know what the arrow means, but I see that you have followed the advice of using `npm`, which is what you should do, good call.

Answer (score 0):

I realized to solve the problem, i just install jquery and popper.js using npm, why the first one did not work while i put bootstrap and jquery as enty in webpack.config.js!!!!

Any one can explain that!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a part of the path in both cases - you should go with

```
.addEntry('bootstrap_js', './assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js')
.addEntry('jquery', './assets/js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js')
```

So basically add **bootstrap/** and **jquery/** accordingly